# Why would this not build on heroku?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

Do you guys see any logical inconsistency here?

I made a few changes to this  section in application.html.erb of a Ruby on Rails file and then when I deployed the new version, Heroku build keeps failing. It used to work just fine earlier, the build issue popped out recently (not sure after which step). Also, there is no explicit error code from Heroku (making it much harder to debug).

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ShopWithMe</title>

  <!--Browser icon, not working yet -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
       href="images/favicon.ico" />

  <!-- Connect to Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />

  <!-- Connect to Font Awesome CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

  <!-- Connect to our own additional CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/product_modal_styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/additional_styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/searchpage.css" />

  <style>
  /* Only necessary if you are using navbar-fixed-top */
  body {
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  </style>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  /* social buttons */
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=596ffabf1328d800122d51d6&product=inline-share-buttons"></script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />



  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    (function(){
    var fc = document.createElement('link'); fc.type = 'text/css'; fc.rel = 'stylesheet';
    fc.href = 'https://product.feedbacklite.com/feedbacklite.css'; h.appendChild(fc);
    })();
    var fbl = {'campaign':{'id':2401, 'type':2, 'size':2, 'body':'666666', 'position':7, 'tab':1, 'control':1, 'auto':1, 'auto_delay':30000, 'auto_expiry':86400000, 'browser':'1234'}};
    (function(){
    var fj = document.createElement('script'); fj.type = 'text/javascript';
    fj.async = true; fj.src = 'https://product.feedbacklite.com/feedbacklite.js'; h.appendChild(fj);
    })();
    </script>


    <!-- from https://codepen.io/RetinaInc/pen/rxksh -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
```

Comment: Can't you just make a copy of the file, back out the changes in that file, and then slowly reintroduce the changes you made until it breaks again? You can also look at the Heroku log and try and work it out that way.

Comment: I don't know if it's related but it seems that you are including bootstrap twice and even different versions.

Comment: @CV-Gate - do you mean the bootstrap.min.js file?

Comment: Yes, that file.

Comment: That was indeed the reason, thanks @CV-Gate